# Does deleting iCloud backup deletes iCloud Photo library?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

The purple color denotes the backup and yellow color for iCloud photos. So does deleting this purple thing which is a backup (which I assume also has all the photos data), deletes the iCloud photo library too?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iCloud Backup, a.k.a. “that purple thing”, does not include any copies of the videos and photos kept through the Photos app on your iPhone when iCloud Photos is activated.

Therefore, deleting an iCloud Backup would have no impact on your photo and video library kept through the Photos app on your iPhone. The deletion would affect neither such photos and videos locally stored on your iPhone nor their copies in iCloud Photos.

Deleting an iCloud backup only deletes *the iCloud backups* of whatever is being backed up to iCloud from your iPhone as part of the iCloud Backup service, not anything on your iPhone and also not any of their copies in iCloud if they have gotten there through an iCloud service other than iCloud Backup such as iCloud Photos.

See the “[What does iCloud back up?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428)” Apple support webpage for more.

Comment: Thanks this helped me to take a decision